# MathJax framework issue

Tags: objective-c, mathjax

I am studying about how to use MathJax by using this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. My problem is when I render mathematic question, the context and mathematic equation stay at the different line not concatenate to each other like normal mathematic equation.

For example:

```
Find x? from this equation x + 2y = 3 , where y = 1 <--- I want it to render like this
```

But MathJax is render like the following:

```
 Find x? from this equation
     x + 2y = 3
 where y = 1
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using in-line math delimiters (like `\(...\)` or `$...$`) and not display math delimiters (like `\[...\]` or `$$...$$`).  It looks like you may have your equation in display math delimiters (though you have not been explicit about the actual markup that you have used).